# How can I set up a authentication in fuseki server for specific user to access with python?

Tags: python, authorization, sparql, fuseki

As I know, there is Apache Shiro for Fuseki webapp.
But I'm trying to set up a authentication in fuseki server for specific user to access with python.

I have been added auth setting in my database config file 
**C:\apache-jena-fuseki-4.3.2\run\configuration\*databaseName.ttl*.** 
And I also add a password file in the same folder.

Then I have been used SPARQLWrapper in python to access database in fuseki. 
But it doesn't work. It says **"HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden"**
I would like to understand what I did wrong and how to do in this issue. 
Can anyone please help me with this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

**databaseName.ttl**:

```
:service_tdb_all  rdf:type            fuseki:Service ;
        rdfs:label                    "TDB databaseName" ;
        fuseki:dataset                :tdb_dataset_readwrite ;
        fuseki:name                   "databaseName" ;
        fuseki:serviceQuery           "query" , "" , "sparql" ;
        fuseki:serviceReadGraphStore  "get" ;
        fuseki:serviceReadWriteGraphStore "data" ;
        fuseki:serviceUpdate          "" , "update" ;
        fuseki:serviceUpload          "upload" ;
        fuseki:passwd  "password_file" ;
        fuseki:auth    "basic" ;
        fuseki:allowedUsers "user1"
```

**password_file**:

```
user1: password
```

**code in python**

```
sparql = SPARQLWrapper(self.query_endpoint_url)
sparql.setQuery(query)
sparql.setHTTPAuth(BASIC)
sparql.setCredentials('user1', 'password')
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
results = sparql.query().convert()
```

**------Updated in 2022/10/13------**

Here is my config file.
And I also remove the auth setup in *databaseName.ttl*
To start the fuseki by *fuseki-server.bat*
Testing the access by the command above with incorrent password.
Access works even if the passoword is incorrect.
`curl -I -user user1:password12 http://localhost:3030`
Testing the access to my endpoint, 
`curl -I --user user1:password http://localhost:3030/databaseName/sparql`
it says **HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed**
**config.ttl**

```
## Fuseki Server configuration file.

@prefix :        <#> .
@prefix fuseki:  <http://jena.apache.org/fuseki#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix ja:      <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#> .
@prefix tdb:    <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2008/tdb#> .

[] rdf:type fuseki:Server ;
        fuseki:passwd  "password_file" ;
        fuseki:auth    "basic" ;
        fuseki:allowedUsers "user1".
```

**databaseName.ttl**

```
@prefix fuseki: <http://jena.apache.org/fuseki#> .
@prefix ja:     <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#> .
@prefix rdf:    <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs:   <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix tdb:    <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2008/tdb#> .

<http://jena.apache.org/2016/tdb#GraphTDB>
        rdfs:subClassOf  ja:Model .

ja:ModelRDFS  rdfs:subClassOf  ja:Model .

ja:RDFDatasetSink  rdfs:subClassOf  ja:RDFDataset .

tdb:DatasetTDB  rdfs:subClassOf  ja:RDFDataset .

<http://jena.apache.org/2016/tdb#GraphTDB2>
        rdfs:subClassOf  ja:Model .

<http://jena.apache.org/text#TextDataset>
        rdfs:subClassOf  ja:RDFDataset .

ja:RDFDatasetZero  rdfs:subClassOf  ja:RDFDataset .

:service_tdb_all  rdf:type            fuseki:Service ;
        rdfs:label                    "TDB databaseName" ;
        fuseki:dataset                :tdb_dataset_readwrite ;
        fuseki:name                   "databaseName" ;
        fuseki:serviceQuery           "query" , "" , "sparql" ;
        fuseki:serviceReadGraphStore  "get" ;
        fuseki:serviceReadWriteGraphStore
                "data" ;
        fuseki:serviceUpdate          "" , "update" ;
        fuseki:serviceUpload          "upload" .

ja:ViewGraph  rdfs:subClassOf  ja:Model .

ja:GraphRDFS  rdfs:subClassOf  ja:Model .

<http://jena.apache.org/2016/tdb#DatasetTDB>
        rdfs:subClassOf  ja:RDFDataset .

tdb:GraphTDB  rdfs:subClassOf  ja:Model .

ja:DatasetTxnMem  rdfs:subClassOf  ja:RDFDataset .

<http://jena.apache.org/2016/tdb#DatasetTDB2>
        rdfs:subClassOf  ja:RDFDataset .

ja:RDFDatasetOne  rdfs:subClassOf  ja:RDFDataset .

ja:MemoryDataset  rdfs:subClassOf  ja:RDFDataset .

:tdb_dataset_readwrite
        rdf:type      tdb:DatasetTDB ;
        tdb:location  "C:\\apache-jena-fuseki-4.3.2\\run/databases/databaseName" .

ja:DatasetRDFS  rdfs:subClassOf  ja:RDFDataset .
```

Comment: does it work with `curl` from command line?

Comment: UninformedUser, Thanks for your comment! :) 

It does't work to connect my **query_endpoint_url**, it says **HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden**

But it works to connect ```http://localhost:3030/``` wtih HTTP/1.1 200 OK.

Comment: Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

The packing of Fuseki you appear to be using supports security via Apache Shiro, not via configuration in the config.ttl.

https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/fuseki-security.html

This form, Fuseki/webapp, has a "run/" area where you can put configuration files.

There is a different packaging - Fuseki/main which supports security in the way you are trying to use it.

This form does not currently (2022) does not have a UI
and it does not layout the configuration as two separate files.

https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/fuseki-main.html
https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/fuseki-data-access-control.html

The following configuration file for Fuseki main works: (and is tidied up):

```
PREFIX :        <#>
PREFIX fuseki:  <http://jena.apache.org/fuseki#>
PREFIX rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX ja:      <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#>
PREFIX tdb:    <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2008/tdb#>

[] rdf:type fuseki:Server ;
        fuseki:passwd  "password_file" ;
        fuseki:auth    "basic" ;
        fuseki:allowedUsers "user1". 

:service_tdb_all  rdf:type            fuseki:Service ;
    rdfs:label                    "TDB databaseName" ;
    fuseki:dataset                :tdb_dataset_readwrite ;
    fuseki:name                   "databaseName" ;
    fuseki:endpoint [ fuseki:operation fuseki:query ; ] ;
    fuseki:endpoint [ fuseki:operation fuseki:update ; ] ;
    fuseki:endpoint [ fuseki:operation fuseki:gsp-rw ; ] ;

    fuseki:endpoint [ fuseki:operation fuseki:query ; fuseki:name "sparql" ];
    fuseki:endpoint [ fuseki:operation fuseki:query ; fuseki:name "query" ];
    fuseki:endpoint [ fuseki:operation fuseki:update ; fuseki:name "update" ];
    fuseki:endpoint [ fuseki:operation fuseki:gsp-r ; fuseki:name "get" ] ;
    fuseki:endpoint [ fuseki:operation fuseki:gsp-rw ; fuseki:name "data" ] ;
    fuseki:endpoint [ fuseki:operation fuseki:upload ; fuseki:name "upload" ] ;
    .
    
:tdb_dataset_readwrite
        rdf:type      tdb:DatasetTDB ;
        tdb:location  "DB" .
```

Authentication (the password file and auth type) is for the server, not the fuseki:Service.

```
... rdf:type fuseki:Server ;
        fuseki:passwd  "password_file" ;
        fuseki:auth    "auth" ;
        ...
```

https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/fuseki-data-access-control.html

What is confusing is that for Fuseki/webapp, the root resources "http://localhost:3030/" is the UI and the UI access is controlled by shiro.ini, defaulting to allowing all local access. If you remove the `-I` (i.e. HTTP HEAD) from curl commands you wil see that you get HTML from http://localhost:3030/.

This is different in Fuseki/main.

The 405 is because a HEAD request to the SPARQL endpoint is not supported http://localhost:3030/databaseName/sparql is bad. A HEAD request on a SPARQL endpoint would require interpreting the query string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I have been trying to set up the authentication in server config file in ```C:\apache-jena-fuseki-4.3.2\run\config.ttl```,
and also the **passoword_file** in the same folder.
Then using ```curl command``` to make sure that the autheritcation works or not.
Access works even if the passoword is incorrect.
It seems the authentication doesn't work. Is there any wrong in my setting?
could you tell me more please ? Thank you.

Comment: Does the password_file have extension? 
And is it OK to setup the password file name **password_file** in config file?

Comment: The value in the configuration file is the password file name, relative to the running process. There is no required choice of extension and if it has an extension, it must be in the string value.

Comment: Provide a complete example of the configuration. We can not see your file!

Comment: AndyS, thanks for replying. I just updated the complete configuration above.
I am new to fuseki and sparql. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.